# Custom string in validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel.
I have this validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required|string',
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'message' => 'required|string',
      'captcha' => 'required|string|secretsstring'
]);

// send message
```

This validation works fine,  but problem is with captcha validation.

I need check catcha == secretsstring

If not - show error.

In my code I have error:

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate secretsstring does
>   not exist.

How can I repair it?

Comment: Try with `in` rule https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-in

Comment: Try it https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#using-closures